# How to get first data from the array?

Tags: html, node.js, function, typescript, filter

I have an issue in the node (html file). I need to get the first data instead of everything. I used this

```
 <% if(tblData) {%>
     <% tblData.forEach(function(res,row) {%>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= res.name %>
          </td>
         </tr>
      <% }) %>
 <% } %>
```

I got all the names. But instead of getting all the names I want only the first name. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the first element of a table by putting its index in square brackets  (`myTable[0]`):

```
<% if(tblData) {%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= tblData[0].name %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

Comment: @Maarti.Thank you. It really helped me.